# Who wins in this case? Or is it tied?

Tags: texas-hold-em

In Texas holdem, the flop had a queen and a pair of 2’s. I had an A and a 10. The other guy had an A and a J. The other 2 cards were irrelevant.Who wins or is it a tie? I read the other post but did not see anything that explained our scenario. Could I just get an actual answer? [Actual hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSXVd.jpg)

Comment: How do you know other two cards are irrelevant?

Comment: The other cards were lower than anything else on the board and weren’t paired to anything.

Comment: How can a card be lower than a 2?

Comment: They were an 8 and a 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost. Your best hand is 2-2-A-Q-10, and your opponent's is 2-2-A-Q-J : his J beats your 10.

If the river had been a King instead of a 5, however, it would have been a tie, both players having 2-2-A-K-Q.